# IllegalArgumentException - variable with FindBy annotation can't be set to Proxy

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Trying to implement Cucumber autotests with Gradle, Java and WebDriver, I'm stuck with some kind of issue I've never met before. When I try to create an instance of a class in the code

```
BoardGameGeekHomePage currentPage = new BoardGameGeekHomePage(driver);
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.ArrayList field pages.BoardGameGeekHomePage.usersOfMainPage to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15

at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:117)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:79)
at pages.AbstractPage.<init>(AbstractPage.java:13)
at pages.BoardGameGeekHomePage.<init>(BoardGameGeekHomePage.java:15)
at steps.CucumberSteps.i_open_the_game_collection_of_a_user(CucumberSteps.java:25)
at ✽.When I open the game collection of a user(Cucumber.feature:5)
```

Here is the code of a BoardGameGeekHomePage class:

```
    package pages;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import static utils.DriverFactory.driver;

    public class BoardGameGeekHomePage extends AbstractPage{

    public BoardGameGeekHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//td/span/a[contains(@ng-href, '/user/')]")
    private ArrayList<WebElement> usersOfMainPage;

    public UserPage selectUserByIndex(int i) {
        usersOfMainPage.get(i).click();
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, UserPage.class);
    }

    public BoardGameGeekHomePage goTo(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
        return PageFactory.initElements(driver, BoardGameGeekHomePage.class);
    }
}
```

and AbstractPage class:

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import static utils.DriverFactory.driver;

public class AbstractPage {
//    protected WebDriver driver;
    public AbstractPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

If I comment @FindBy annotation, in BoardGameGeekHomePage class, then code will be executed properly (of course I'll get NullPointerException because ArrayList will be empty).
Hope to hear some ideas.

Comment: Try using plain `List` instead of `ArrayList`?

Comment: And... it seems to be working. What's the root cause of this issue?

Comment: `List` is an Interface and `ArrayList` is a class which implements the `List` interface. The object you are getting back implements the List interface but is not an `ArrayList` that is why you need to use the interface `List`